# How to fix setContentView and super.onCreate methods using a class and subclass?

Tags: java, android

so I am trying to load different button outputs into subclasses, so I require setContentView and onCreate methods (I think) so I can trigger the findViewById functions to trigger different methods for using the buttons.

I have the wrong code here

```
public class LoadGuitar { 

 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_berries);
```

It shows problems on onCreate, and setContentView, and it seems to be effecting the whole project with errors. Has anybody ran into this problem that causes the one to show up incorrect? This only applies to my subclass labelled LoadGuitar. In my main class...

```
public class Berries extends LoadGuitar {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_berries);
```

it works fine!

Please if anyone can help me with this problem. Thank you.

Comment: These methods are only part of the Activity class. This seems like an XY problem. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to apply findViewbyId() methods inside the subclass, but it will not read them in the subclass

Comment: So I can apply different listeners per sub class

Comment: `LoadGuitar` isn't a subclass. It doesn't extend anything.

Comment: are you saying if LoadGuitar extends Berries, would it read and do findViewById()?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I am trying to get LoadGuitar to load a predefined findViewById() function to load the buttons so it can read certain toggle states. is it possible?

Comment: sorry not a subclass, but a seperate class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oncreate() and setcontentview() are defined in Activity class;in order to override or call them you must extend Activity class with LoadGuitar;

```
public class LoadGuitar extends Activity{ 

 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_berries);
    ...
}
```

Comment: wait now it says it cannot resolve symbol for Activity?

Comment: is your jdk and gradle set up?